# SQL: Order by Tree BUT skip closed subtrees

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table. This is a tree structure where the path column shows the full path from the root of the tree to the particular node:

```
Path    | ParentName | ChildName | includeSubTree
1       | Null       | Root      | true
1.1     | Root       | RC1       | true 
1.1.1   | RC1        | RC11      | true
1.2     | Root       | RC2       | false
1.2.1   | RC2        | RC21      | true
1.2.1.1 | RC21       | RC211     | true
```

My goal is to have a select statement which:

1. Returns all rows
2. Sorted by path
3. Ignoring all rows which have a parent with includeSubTree set to false

Taking the above example, Path 1.2 has includeSubtree set to false therefore I want to ignore all of its children regardless of whether they have includeSubtree set to true or false.

My query would therefore return just the following paths:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
```

Essentially what I am looking to do is to temporarily remove whole subtrees.

I have been stuck on this for quite some time now and wondering if anyone can give me some pointers?

I am using SQLite at the moment but happy for answers that would work with another SQL system. So far I have got as far as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TreeStructure 
WHERE includeSubTree = true 
ORDER BY Path;
```

The obvious problem here is that this will include 1.2.1 even though 1.2 has includeSubTree set to false.

I am at the start of this project so happy to change the schema if necessary.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: with ms-sql this can be easily done with [recursive](http://stevestedman.com/2012/02/generating-a-tree-path-with-a-cte/) [cte](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/06/simple-family-tree-query-using.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . You can use a correlated subquery with `exists` to see if something should be excluded.

```
select t.*
from tree t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tree t2
                  where t2.includeSubTree = false and
                        t.path like concat(t2.path, '.%')
                 ) and
      t.includeSubTree = true;
```

Note:  Although `concat()` is ANSI standard, some databases spell it as `+`, `||`, or even `&`.